# ie 7 doesn't work with CSS inline-block or fixes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I know that this has been asked a million times before, but nothing that I have tried has solved the problem. I'm working on a nice looking `<select>` type thing. I'm basing it off of common CSS drop down navigation menus (using nested `<ul>`s and `<li>`s, just with a few tweaks. One of the tweaks is that I need it to display inline (without floating it because it goes past any other elements in the same line as it, and I don't want to float everything else around it). I've got it working well in the browsers besides ie 7 (and probably anything lower, but I don't need anything lower than ie7). Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ralokz/hjDVS/2/

If you look at that in any non-ie7 browser, it looks like how I want it to:

[image: good menu]

But if you look at it in ie7, it looks like this:

[image: bad menu]

One site that I saw come up a lot for the inline-block fix is this: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/. That worked for ie8, but unfortunately ie7 still doesn't look right.

Is there any other way to fix inline-block for ie7? Or, is there a CSS alternative to make sure the the second level `<li>`s are always vertically aligned with the the first level `<li>`? Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't appear to be anything to do with `inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:
`position:relative;` to `div.dropdown ul li`, get rid of the margins on `div.dropdown ul li ul` and set it's `top:25px`, `left:-1px;`, `width:100%`; finally, set `div.dropdown ul li ul li` to `margin:0;` delete the left-right padding, and set `width:100%` ...

I might have missed something, but here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hjDVS/7/

I think your real problem was the absolutely positioned `ul`

Comment: Correct. You often need to explicitly set `top` and `left` for IE7.

Answer (score 3):

IE6 and IE7 do support `inline-block`, but they have a major bug with it: They only support it on elements which have a default display style of `inline`.

Therefore `span {display:inline-block;}` will work, but `div {display:inline-block;}` doesn't.

If this is an issue for you, there's good news: they have another bug, which makes `inline` work the way `inline-block` is supposed to in some cases, so you may be able to simply use `display:inline;`.

If you are going to do this, you need to be careful to make sure that only IE6 and IE7 do this, as other browsers will need a proper `inline-block;` style. Some browser-specific hacks or conditional comments may be required to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For each rule with `display:inline-block`, in the IE 7 stylesheet put `zoom:1; display:inline;` This works with all elements, and works about the same way.